# Google Play Music draining humongous amounts of battery

Tags: battery, battery-life, google-play-services, google-play-music

Around a couple of weeks back, my phone battery started draining really quickly. In the battery settings view, I could see that Google Play Music is consuming huge amounts of battery.

I have tried reporting the app, so far gotten no response. Other measures such as Force Close, removing permissions, restricting background data access haven't had any effect as well.

I even performed a factory reset a couple of days back, reinstalled all apps, but to no avail. As a last measure, I disabled the app (restore to factory version). Although after I did this, the battery hogging didn't stop, in fact it increased. And it's almost using ALL of the battery. Refer screenshots attached.

[image: CPU Usage]
[image: Battery Usage]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's a system app and conventional approaches like greenify won't help. IMO, best is to root the device, convert it into user app and Greenify or freeze it and use another music player. Alternatively, if there is an update available for your device (BTW, which is that and Android version? ) , see if updating Android helps

Comment: When you disable Music, what app is causing the drain then?  Music?  That would be unusual....Things I would do: clear cache, disable app, reboot.  Then check results.  As beeshyams asks, what Android version and is it up to date?

Comment: It's a Moto I guess. Afaik, an app is not supposed to run if it's disabled. Tell us what happened after disabling the app? Which app is then draining the battery?

Comment: Can you install another app such as GSam battery monitor and see if it says the same thing? I've found the system battery usage monitor is flaky.

Comment: If you are not rooted, your best bet is to keep an eye out for update that may fix the issue. Luckily, google likes to update *their* favorite apps frequently. This is why people go through trouble to root their devices, that they bought - to make it work the way they want and not how the manufacturer/google is imposing.